# Magento 2: developer mode breaks magento command line

Tags: installation, developer-mode

Right after installing magento, (2.3.2),
I run

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

to enable developer mode. I remember when I had done before without setting this flag, the instance worked fine.

This command succeeded, but right after that, I am not even able to run any of the Magento commands.

Even the command to know the current status fails

```
>bin/magento deploy:mode:show         
Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist
```

(since magento command itself is broken, di:compile or even turning off the developer mode will fail).

I could salvage the situation by copying the generated files from my another instance.  But I am not sure why this happens and how to force it to regenerate the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands from the Magento root terminal

```
cd <your Magento install directory>/var
rm -rf cache/* di/* generation/* page_cache/*
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Also, run the below commands from terminal:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: I deleted them, but still bin/magento deploy:mode:show is not working.

Comment: Give permission to var, pub and generated folder with this command "chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/"

Comment: thanks sumit, yes, I did that too.   Setting to developer mode clearly deletes the generated folder, which seems to be needed for the magento tool itself to work.

Comment: Yes, you need to run the deployment commands again to make it work. I've updated my answer for the same.

Comment: This is what I meant @melchi - I've deleted my answer as Sumit's explains it better :P

Comment: I've learned this from you, Ben :)

Comment: Thanks ben, sumit.  no mater what I do, It just cleans up generated folder and cribs about missing proxy class.  I kept rsyncing them in, to run my next command.  I think I will stick to default mode, I believe making it developer mode some how is broken.

Comment: after marking it as developer mode, bin/magento setup:upgrade is failing, as any other magento command.  so I rsynced the generated folder to run the setup:upgrade

Comment: Check the .htaccess file as well placed under /pub/static folder. This is also required.